# Space between but its two divs inside a div inside a div (not working)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm starting with HTML,CSS and JS and I'm trying to do a weather App. I want it to have the temperature, then the city and its weather(with an icon) **and then** some extra info like humidity and wind, I pictured these as 3 different columns. Which worked, until I wanted to do another 2 columns inside the extra info column(last one) I want it to look, like this for every type of info:

> Humidity___________________ 30%

Where the "__" are blank spaces using 'space-between'. I have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2gepbrx/) where I portrayed the issue, you can see these 2 columns are sticked together, how do I change this? and how can I do it in a way that adapts to screen-size, so the space-between varies and I don't use a static margin value or something like that.

```css
* {
  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 98vw;
}

p {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.divSearch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#searchBar {
  width: 260px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#searchIcon {
  width: 42px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 63)
}

.recentCity {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 12px;
}

.cityStats {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 12px;
  width: 540px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#temperature {
  font-size: 82px;
  margin-right: 26px;
}

#temperature span {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.divExtraInfo {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

#spaceBetween {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="cityStats">
  <div id="divTemperature">
    <p id="temperature"> 19°<span>C</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="divExtraInfo">
    <p id="city">Rosario</p>
    <p id="weatherText"> <span id="weatherIcon">☀</span> Sunny</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divExtraInfo" id="spaceBetween">
    <div>
      <p id="windSpeed"> Wind</p>
      <p id="humidity">Humidity</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="windSpeedKM"> 32km/h</p>
      <p id="humidity%">62%</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pus3jmLh/7/) that may answer you question but I'm not 100% sure if it's what you're looking for. It should scale as I've used `vw`.

Comment: Please put the actual code from the fiddle in the answer in case it ever changes your answer maintains the highest value to the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

Using display grid will help you eliminate the need for predetermined widths; Using flex and auto margins you can align the temperature stats to the left and right. The misalignment of the text you see is caused by the icon you can edit that with some more css alignment as well.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.container{
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

.temperature {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.quick-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}


.conditions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.condition {
  display: flex;
}

.condition-stat{  
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<div class="container">
  <p class="temperature"> 19°<span>C</span></p>
  <div class="quick-info">
    <p>Rosario</p>
    <p>☀ Sunny</p>
  </div>
  <div class="conditions">
    <div class="condition">
      <p>Wind</p>
      <p class="condition-stat">32km/h</p>
    </div>
    <div class="condition">
      <p>Humidity</p>
      <p class="condition-stat">62%</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's very useful, do you recommend any video that explains grid correctly? should i always use grid display instead of flex for this types of alignments?

Comment: I just realized that with this method the stats always hug the right corner, i dont want that.  I understand that i can move it to the left using margin, but thats the same issue i had earlier, right? like if i use too much right-margin it will break in smaller screens, same as if i added marginleft to the code posted in the question. I want to assign a maxwidth to the 3columns(which is 60vw) and use any excess space to separate the stats.

Comment: Hey @ValentínSanabria, the current solution is all with relative positioning's, and auto margins. I could further help if you edited your post with an example of how you want things to look.

Answer (score 0):

use `padding-right` to fix this:

```css
* {

  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body {

  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 98vw;
}

p {

  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.divSearch {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

}

#searchBar {

  width: 260px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#searchIcon {

  width: 42px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 63)
}

.recentCity {

  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 12px;

}

.cityStats {

  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  margin-left: 12px;
  width: 540px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#temperature {

  font-size: 82px;
  margin-right: 26px;
}

#temperature span {

  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.divExtraInfo {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 130px;

}

#spaceBetween {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="cityStats">

      <div id="divTemperature">

        <p id="temperature"> 19°<span>C</span></p>

      </div>

      <div class="divExtraInfo">

        <p id="city">Rosario</p>
        <p id="weatherText"> <span id="weatherIcon">☀</span> Sunny</p>

      </div>

      <div class="divExtraInfo" id="spaceBetween">

        <div>

          <p id="windSpeed"> Wind</p>
          <p id="humidity">Humidity</p>

        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:30px">

          <p id="windSpeedKM">32km/h</p>
          <p id="humidity%">62%</p>

        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: The thing is, thats a static value.. it wont change with screen resolution so if i put a higher padding it would break in smaller screens. How do i make it responsive with a minimum padding value that can increase

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking down the layout in to "containers" - here I used a "group-container" for things that "stack" like the city name and weather.  I also set up a "container" using a class city-container which has three "groups" under it.  I then set the last group to `margin-left: auto;` to that it gets pushed to the far right no matter what the actual width is.  Note that you can set the "block/group" width of those to make them line up vertically better but I leave that for an exercise.  Note the question here is then pushing values to the right of labels so that is done with `.group-container .content-text:nth-child(n+1){ margin-left:auto; }`  where `n+1` indicates the second "child" of a group-container (the values) where `n+0` would be the 0 child (the label) for the 0 based values. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

I then had some fun and set up multiple "cities" but this also illustrates longer city names and some color using data attributes and some CSS for those values.

NOTE: the city names wrap odd due to your `.extra-info { max-width: 150px; min-width: 130px; }` - setting that slightly wider would probably be better here.

```js
var readings = [{
  name: "El Desertos",
  weather: {
    name: "Sunny",
    type: "sunny"
  },
  temperature: 35,
  windspeed: 17,
  humidity: 9
}, {
  name: "Nome",
  weather: {
    name: "Snow",
    type: "snow"
  },
  temperature: -2,
  windspeed: 7,
  humidity: 11
}, {
  name: "Inferno",
  weather: {
    name: "Very Hot",
    type: "hot"
  },
  temperature: 42,
  windspeed: 45,
  humidity: 2
}, {
  name: "Jungle City",
  weather: {
    name: "Wet and warm",
    type: "rain"
  },
  temperature: 32,
  windspeed: 5,
  humidity: 96
}];
const cityWeather = document.getElementById('cities')
const cityStats = cityWeather.querySelector('.city-stats');
//  console.log( cityWeather.querySelector('.city').textContent);

//const cityCopy = cityStats.cloneNode(true);
//console.log(cityCopy);
readings.forEach(city => {
  cityClone = cityStats.cloneNode(true);;
  //   console.log(cityClone);
  cityClone.querySelector('.city').textContent = city.name;
  //  console.log( cityClone.querySelector('.city').textContent);

  cityClone.querySelector('.temperature').textContent = city.temperature;
  cityClone.querySelector('.wind-speed').textContent = city.windspeed;
  cityClone.querySelector('.humidity-percent').textContent = city.humidity;
  cityClone.querySelector('.weather-text').textContent = city.weather.name;
  cityClone.querySelector('.weather-icon').dataset.icon = city.weather.type;
  //console.log(city.weather.type);
  cityWeather.appendChild(cityClone);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(41, 35, 35);
  height: 96vh;
  width: 98vw;
}

.group-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.group-container .content-text:nth-child(n+1){
  margin-left:auto;
}

.city-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ffddff;
}

.city-stats {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  /* width: 540px;*/
  text-align: left;
}

.temperature-container {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1.625rem;
}

.temperature-scale {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.extra-info {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

.extra-info-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content-text {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.weather-icon[data-icon="sunny"] {
  color: yellow;
}

.weather-icon[data-icon="snow"] {
  color: white;
}

.weather-icon[data-icon="rain"] {
  color: blue;
}

.weather-icon[data-icon="hot"] {
  color: red;
}

.content-text-label {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cities">
  <div class="city-container city-stats">
    <div class="group-container temperature-container">
      <div class="content-text"><span class="temperature">19</span><span class="temperature-degree">°</span><span class="temperature-scale">C</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group-container extra-info">
      <div class="content-text city">Rosario</div>
      <div class="content-text"><span class="weather-icon" data-icon="sunny">☀</span><span class="weather-text">Sunny</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group-container extra-info-container">
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="content-text content-text-label">Wind</div>
        <div class="content-text content-text-label">Humidity</div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="content-text"><span class="wind-speed windSpeedKM">32</span><span>km/h</span></div>
        <div class="content-text humidity-percent">62<span class="percent-label">%</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```